# Animate dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

I have this navigation menu and I have one dropdown item in it. I'd like the drop down menu to slowly expand when drops. I can't quite figure out how to do that. I tried css translate height but it didn't work.

I use bootstrap4, jquery, fontawesome4

Here is my code - please view in full screen:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('active')
  })
  $('ul li').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 100px;
  background: #262626;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header .logo {
  height: 61px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 13px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  /* dropdown */
}

header nav ul li.dropdown:before {
  /* dropdown */
  content: '\f0d7';
  font-family: "fontAwesome";
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 61px;
  color: #fff;
  right: 5px;
}

header nav ul li.active.dropdown:before {
  /* dropdown */
  content: '\f0d8';
}

header nav ul li ul {
  /* dropdown */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: #333;
  display: none;
}

header nav ul li.active ul {
  /* dropdown */
  display: block;
}

header nav ul li ul li {
  /* dropdown */
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

header nav ul li a {
  height: 61px;
  line-height: 61px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

header nav ul li a:hover,
header nav ul li a.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #2196f3;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 1200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1200ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1200ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1200ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 1200ms ease;
}

.menu-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  line-height: 61px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  header {
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  header nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    background: #333;
    top: 61px;
    left: -100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  header nav.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  header nav ul {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  header nav ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  }
  header nav ul li.active ul {
    /* dropdown */
    position: relative;
    background: #003e6f;
  }
  header nav ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>

  <div class="logo"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt=""></div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>

</header>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet, as you could have done too

Answer (score 1):

Display: none should use. Try to get opacity from 0 to 1

```
 .dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform-origin: top;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  transform: scale(0.9, 0.7);
  display: block; 
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  transform: scale(1, 1) translateY(0);  
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```